# Authenticate User on MongoDB with .NET Driver 2.4

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The following code works as it should do, if the server is running and if the usename and password are correct. However, if i give a wrong username or password, it does not give me feedback, but only runs into a timeout when calling the Count method.

```
MongoClientSettings setts = new MongoClientSettings()
                    {
                        Server = new MongoServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017),
                        Credentials = new MongoCredential[] { MongoCredential.CreateCredential("TestDatabase", "username", "password") }
                    };
this.client = new MongoClient(setts);    
this.client.Cluster.DescriptionChanged += this.ClusterDescriptionChanged;
var database = this.client.GetDatabase("TestDatabase");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("SimpleCollection");
var count = collection.Count(MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty);
```

**How do i get error messages from the driver and how can i check if it's the connection, the user or the password that does not fit?**

PS: The driver API has changed a lot since 2.0 in Jan.2016, which means that most webtutorials and posts on this site no longer work for the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the client, you can check if the connection is successful

```
var server = client.GetServer();
server.Ping();
```

Also it is always a good idea to enclose your code in a try catch with timeout exception because that is expected.

for more info on this you can refer [MongoDB C# Driver check Authentication status & Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354983/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-check-authentication-status-role)

Comment: Thanks your the answer. My client does not have a GetServer()-Method. Which version are you refering to? The example you linked does not offer a solution. The mentioned "auth failed"-Text is not part of the exception. Now its just a timeout and i still can't figure out if the password is bad or someone cut the cable.

Comment: from my experience mongo exceptions are not evolved to a better level yet. the best way to make sure if you got a connection or not is to see if you are connected to server or not. if you got a succesful connection you should be able to poll server.

Comment: `client.GetServer()` is part of the driver v.1. and has been removed in v.2